# C# winform, App Crashing after using the Video/Audio classes from the Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback dll

Tags: c#, winforms, directx, audiovideoplayback

I'm working with some Audio files in my app (mp3, wav, ..etc)
I was using the Audio Class from the Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback dll
so first I had to download the dll, after doing so, I went to **Add Reference**
then I browsed to the dll location, and added it
I also installed the **DirectX 9.0 Web Setup**

Now, i don't get any problem with just saying: `Audio aud;`
but if I do something like this:

```
Audio aud = new Audio(path);
```

or

```
Video vid = new Video(path);
```

if I press `Ctrl+F5` the app will crash immediately, If i try to debug, I just can't see the debugging cursor, and if i keep pressing F10 nothing ever happens ..
I put it in a `try/catch` block, it didn't threw an exception ..

so what's goin on ?
how can i fix this ?

I even tried to make a whole new app, here's the whole code, there's nothing really in it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound;
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;
using Microsoft.DirectX;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      Audio aud = new Audio("C:\\Users\\vexe\\Desktop\\Songs\\Kimosabe.mp3");
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated ..
Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your project:

```
using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound
using Microsoft.DirectX
```

Comment: change your app.config like this:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: Could you Please tell me how exactly can I reach this file ?
cuz I'm getting confused ..

Comment: i think version of directx you already installed have problem,but if you want to work with audio file the best chose is "fmod.dll" it have a lot of option for working with audio file:http://www.fmod.org/